# Is there a way to map 2 database fields to a custom object in JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In our database at the moment, we have two fields: location_lat and location_lng. In Java, we would map these two fields as separate float variables. In this case, would it be possible to map these two separate float fields into one object (E.g LatLng object) For GET, PUT etc...

Normally, the two fields would look like:

```java
@Column(name = "location_lat")
private float lat;

@Column(name = "location_lng")
private float lng;
```

But it would be nice to have something along the lines of

```java
@Column(name = "lat") AND @Column(name = "lng")
private LatLng location;
```

Something along them lines

Comment: Why dont you just do a getter called ”getLocation()” and in that return a ”new LatLong(lat, long);”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. What you are looking for are the `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` .

First , annotate `@Embeddable` on `LatLng` class:

```
@Embeddable
public class LatLng {
   @Column(name = "location_lat")
   private float lat;

   @Column(name = "location_lng")
   private float lng;
}
```

To use it :

```
@Embedded
private LatLng lat;
```

By default , it will map to the columns defined in `@Embeddable`. To override them to map to other columns. You can use `@AttributeOverrides`:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="lat", column=@Column(name="LAT_COLUMN_XXX")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="lng", column=@Column(name="LNG_COLUMN_YYY"))
})
private LatLng lat;
```

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you very much